# From table to float layout

Tags: html, css

As I heard it's better to avoid page table layout.

I have the following page: http://leroma.org.ua/index0.html

1. I want to have a header 15% size of viewport - solved with JS, because body doesn't have 100% height;
   I want to have a scaled by height logo on the left of the header (it has height as header, but width is scaled proportionally) - solved by adding max-width, max-height:100%;
   Now wallpaper is located under the image.
   How can I place it between left image and right border?
2. buttons_table looks fine, but how can I make the same not using tables?

   Correct me if my implementation can be better.

Comment: I don't know where you have that JS you talk about. I cannot se it anywhere

Comment: Added script in the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add this

   ```
   html,body,#page {height: 100%}
   #header {height: 15%}
   #header_wallpaper {overflow: hidden}
   ```

   No JS necessary
2. Check modernizr.com

   there is a community addon css-displaytable
   Use

   ```
   display: table  
   display: table-row  
   display: table-cell
   ```

Comment: 1) Works great. 2) I'll try display: table... Am I right if I need Modernizer just for cross-browser page styling?

Comment: Yes. Modernize is a good way to keep track of what CSS is the user's browser capable of and present other CSS style to older browsers.